# Gauss' Lemma: $r_1, \ldots, r_k, p - s_1, \ldots, p-s_{\nu}$ are all incongruent where $r_i, s_j$ are least residues.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble understanding a step in the below proof of Gauss' Lemma.

I see that $r_1, \ldots, r_k, p - s_1, \ldots, p-s_{\nu}$
 are all less than $p/2$ and it follows that $r_1,\ldots, r_k$ are pairwise incongruent as well are $p - s_1, \ldots, p-s_{\nu}$.

However to prove that $r_i$ are incongruent to $p-s_j$, I don't understand the steps. Why is it a contradiction that $r_i + s_i \equiv 0 (\mod p)$ ? (why does the author claim $s_i < p/2$, when $s_j$ is an element $> p/2$ ?)

Could someone give me an explanation ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, we do not have $s_j<\frac{p}{2}$. The argument is easily fixed however with a similar step as the previous  paragraph.

$r_i \equiv  p-s_j$ implies $t_i a \equiv -t_j a$, some $t_i, t_j$ with $1 \leq t_i, t_j \leq \frac{p-1}{2}$. This yields a contradiction as $0<t_i+t_j \leq p-1$. (or if you prefer, use $u_i, u_j$ instead so you don't reuse the same letter from the previous paragraph)

Comment: Thank you @IvanLoh ! So the author made a mistake I guess ?